# Firebase increment in batch by multiple users within 10 seconds updating a field

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, batch-processing

I made a POS system with c# Windows Form and used Firebase as the system is online.

I do batch writes and one of the writes does an incremement to the overall company value.

So you have 2 POSs running at the same time. The only field they both increment or decrement is the overall company value. Everything else is a separate document or collection.

So a few days a go, branch 1 made a sale at 09:33:11 and branch 2 made a sale at 09:33:20

I first start the batch write...
Then record the transaction so both transactions were added to their respective collection.
Then they update (using increment) on the company balance.

Well, branch 1 updated but the value of branch 2 did not update the value.

So the question is, am i supposed to be using Transactions here and not batch writes?
I used increment inside the batch write. So both POS basically had their batches run successfully but Branch 2's sale did not add to the company value (1 db.incrmeent field) did not work but everything else did without a fail.

Thanks

I did a deep dive and found that if I recalculate the company value Branch 2's sale's amount did not add to the company account.

I tried recreating the scenario and only using 1 POS there isn't a way where the company value does not update.

I am now wondering if using batch writes was the wrong move as I need to do transactions?

Comment: Welcome to SO. While the question is clear, this site is for coding specific issue. Write some code and when you get stuck, post your code and troubleshooting and we'll take a look. It really sounds like you have a coding problem but we would need to see a duplicatable issue to really be of any help.

Comment: Hi, well that's the thing, I wasn't able to duplicate the problem, I'm assuming it was a concurrency issue even if I'm using the increment function of firebase. I've tried to do multiple sales and it works fine. But because they happened very close I'm assuming it was the issue of reading the incorrect data. Plus from what I'm reading seems like transactions is more safer. My solution for now is just separate all accounts to avoid clashed and then combine them during reporting.